# Why I must I declare self.cards in the __init__() definition, rather than the __str__() definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading source code from a book of mine, and I'm finding the output for some of the source code perplexing. I think it's better I showed you than try to fully explain it.

```
class Cards(object):
   RANK=["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]
   SUIT=["c","d","h","s"]

   def __init__(self,rank,suit):
      self.rank=rank
      self.suit=suit

   def __str__(self):
      rep=self.rank+self.suit
      return rep


class Hand(object):
   def __str__(self):
      self.cards=[]
      if self.cards:
         rep=" "
         for card in self.cards:
          rep+=str(card) + "  "
      else:
         rep="<empty>"

      return rep

   def add(self,card):
      self.cards.append(card)

   def give(self, card, other_hand):
      self.cards.remove(card)
      other_hand.add(card)


b=Cards(rank="A", suit="c")

myhand=Hand()
print(myhand)

myhand.add(b)
print(myhand)
```

In this instance, the interpreter returns a value of empty on both occasions, even when I give self.card two values. However, if I declare the    **init**() method, and first initialize self.card in that one, then it'll run normally and give me the new value of myhand, which will be whatever I added into it's self.card attribute. However, why must I first declare and intialize first.card in the init function? Why can it work the same way in the str function? Is it because the **init**() function is first executed when i first call the class or what?

In addition, where I put rep=str(card), if I change card to self.cards, it starts giving me the memory addresses when I tell it to print. Again, why is this? Why doesn't it just show me the values of self.cards within rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter is returning `<empty>` because every time you call `print(myhand)`, the interpreter prints what `myhand.__str__()` returns. In this example you are:

1. Settings `self.cards` to and empty list.
2. Checking if `self.cards` is not empty, which is *false*.
3. Code proceeds to the `else:` clause returning `<empty>`.

If you put `self.cards = []` inside `__init__` method, which is called only once, after the object has been created, and  remove the aforementioned line from `__str__` then it should work fine - the list of cards won't be overwritten.

Also, `str(self.cards)` is giving you a list of memory addresses, because `str` method of `list` object uses `__repr__` to print the values of itself. If you define a method `__repr__` in `Cards` class, similar to `__str__` then it will work fine.

```
class NoRepr(object):
     def __str__(self):
         return '__str__'     

class WithRepr(object):
     def __str__(self):
         return '__str__'
     def __repr__(self):
         return '__repr__'


[NoRepr(), NoRepr()]
[<__main__.NoRepr at 0x9907c0c>, <__main__.NoRepr at 0x9907a4c>]

[WithRepr(), WithRepr()]
[__repr__, __repr__]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Empty Hand Question

- The `__init__` method is invoked when you create an instance of the class.
- The reason it shows empty is because the statement `self.cards=[]` clears the cards list. Therefore when you print how many cards you have, there are none.

The first error was masked by the fact that you printed the hand before adding `b` to it. If instead the code looked like:

```
myhand=Hand()
myhand.add(b)
print(myhand)
```

the statement `if self.cards:` would give you the error: `AttributeError: 'Hand' object has no attribute 'cards'`

---

#### String Representation Question

- `rep=str(self.cards)` invokes the `str` method on a python list object, since since it is a list of `Cards` objects. That method will call `__repr__` on each object in the list. To fix it, define the method below.

```py
# Cards class
def __repr__(self):
   return str(self)
```